# call huggingface tokenizer in c#

Tags: python, c#, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I would like to call huggingface tokenizer in C# and wonder what might be the best way to achieve this. Specifically, I'd like to use mt5 tokenizer for CJK languages in C#.

I have seen certain nuget packages developed such as [BertTokenizer in C#](https://github.com/NMZivkovic/BertTokenizers), However they do not have consistency with MT5 in huggingface.